# Autofs/Automount in SmartOS (Solaris)

Tags: solaris, mount, automount, smartos

Faced with a trouble using Autofs in **SmartOS**.
I added single line in **/etc/auto_master**:

```
/-      auto_share
```

Here is **/etc/auto_share**'s content:

```
/Public    -rw      10.0.1.20:/nfs/Public
```

10.0.1.20 is WD MyCloud NAS, that why **/nfs/** needed.
Anyway, simple `mount 10.0.1.20:/nfs/Public /Public_test` works well, but after 
 `svcadm enable autofs && automount` 
 I see new folder **/Public** but `ls /Public` says **No such file or directory**.
I'm little bit confused, because same case works like a charm in Linux and OS X, but not in SmartOS. Am I missing something?
I tried also inderect share `/root auto_share` & `Public 10.0.1.20:/nfs/Public` and adding `-fstype=nfs`, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I just should to get more info about Solaris administration tools.

```
svcs -l autofs
```

gave me information that some services necessary for **autofs** are offline:

```
dependency   require_all/none svc:/system/filesystem/local (online)
dependency   require_all/restart svc:/milestone/name-services (online)
dependency   optional_all/none svc:/network/nfs/client (disabled)
dependency   require_all/restart svc:/network/rpc/bind (disabled)
```

So, a couple of commands...

```
svcadm enable svc:/network/rpc/bind
svcadm enable svc:/network/nfs/client
```

...and everything works like a charm.
Sorry for noob question) Hope this information will be useful for someone.